# how to get the value of "CrmOwinAuth" in ms dynamics?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I was making a request through my browser console to my MS Dynamics instance to retrieve some information. I downloaded the network request made and converted it into a curl request. Then, imported that curl request into postman and made a GET request. I got the same results in both cases. But, in the request, there is a parameter called "CrmOwinAuth".

I want to get the value of this parameter. I made another POST request to get my access token of MS Dynamics and compared the value of it with this "CrmOwinAuth" but, they were different.

Can anyone please tell me how can I get the value of this CrmOwinAuth? I need this value to make my curl request for some other user and retrieve its information from ms dynamics.

Comment: can you explain why you need this "CrmOwinAuth" parameter in your request? because you don't need it

Comment: @GuidoPreite I am actually writing a crawler for ms dynamics. In fact, I am using your wonderful tool Dataverse Rest Builder to make a custom API to retrieve the business unit of the user. I copied the entire fetch API code and tried to use that code inside my JS file. That code is working as expected when I try to run it inside the console of the logged-in dynamics window, but when I converted it into a CURL request and hit the request through POSTMAN, it is giving a 401 error. I can't directly use the XRM.utility API inside my code. Is there an equivalent REST API?

Comment: if the Web API request is made outside the Dynamics context (as your case if I understood correctly) you need to provide a Bearer Token for the authentication. In order to get a Bearer Token you can for example use a clientid-clientsecret in order to get it first and after use it inside your requests. This blog post explain a bit the logic behind the process https://www.crmanswers.net/2022/01/dataverse-web-api-and-rest-client-vs.html